# Obtener estilo de div vacío

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

¡Hola!

Estoy haciendo scraping con **BeautifulSoup4** y tengo un problema a la hora de obtener el estilo de un div cuyo contenido está vacío.

El código HTML es:

```
<ul>
    <li class="10EZ ABZ">
        <div class="Mt1" style="background-color: #000; color: #FFF; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="10EZ">
        <div class="Mt1" style="background-color: #FFF; color: #000; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

El problema que me encuentro (creo) es que como el div está vacío, BS4 directamente me devuelve vacío en vez del código html como tal.

¿Cómo podría obtener el estilo del div **Mt1** del primer elemento li?

En su defecto había pensado en obtener el contenido del primer li y posteriormente obtener el style manipulando la cadena.

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay problema con que el `div` no tenga contenido. Cada elemento es parseado por bs4 a un objeto `bs4.element.Tag` que se comporta de forma similar a un diccionario Python. Para acceder al estilo o cualquier otro atributo basta con que uses la sintaxis propia de los diccionarios cuando se quiere obtener el valor de una clave:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """\
<ul>
    <li class="10EZ ABZ">
        <div class="Mt1" style="background-color: #000; color: #FFF; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="10EZ">
        <div class="Mt1" style="background-color: #FFF; color: #000; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

---

```
print(soup.find(class_="Mt1")["style"])
```

> background-color: #000; color: #FFF; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;

Si se pudiera dar el caso que una etiqueta no tuviera el atributo `style` definido, debes manejar la excepción `KeyError` o usar `dict.get`:

```
print(soup.find(class_="Mt1").get("style"))
```

> background-color: #000; color: #FFF; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;

```
for div in soup.find_all(class_="Mt1"):
    print(div.get("style"))
```

> background-color: #000; color: #FFF; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;
>   background-color: #FFF; color: #000; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;

Obviamente también puedes obtenerlo desde el `li`:

```
print(soup.find(class_="10EZ ABZ").div["style"])
```

Comment: Gracias a tu respuesta pude entender mejor el funcionamiento y encontré el error. El problema es que la web debe generar ese contenido de manera dinámica y no llega a cargar esa parte del código fuente, por lo que BS4 no encuentra nada. Un saludo!